# How do I iterate over bash script flags and use them?

Tags: bash, getopts

I have a code that I wrap with a bash script, and I want to know if a certain flag was given (-b), and if so, to update some variable I have in the script (called "x"). Unfortunately, I need this to be done on the bash script, and the synthax here drives me nuts. A small example of what I did is (without the call to the code I wrap):

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0

while getopts :b opt; do
  case $opt in
    b) x=1;;
    ?) echo "";;
  esac
done

echo "x is ${x}"
```

My problem is with having more than one flag I want to pass to the command line.
I tried to use:
`while getopts :b:f:c opt; do`..., but it looks like it fails to work when I do not give the flags in the `-b -f ... -c ...` order (I get `x is 0` when I expect it to be `x is 1`).

Moreover, this does not work when I want to give flags with the `--` prefix (`--frame` instead of `-f`).

What should be the code for this purpose? I tried a few options but I do not manage to figure out what should the synthax exactly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example works for me (not the long options (`--`) part): I get `x is 1` if I pass `-b`. Could you provide a [mcve]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### TL;DR

Options with argument have a colon **after** their character in the `optstring`. So `getopts :b:c:f` means:

- you have a `-b` option that takes an argument (`b:`)
- you have a `-c` option that takes an argument (`c:`)
- you have a `-f` option that takes no argument (`f`)
- use silent error reporting (the leading colon)

If you use `while getopts :b:f:c opt; do...` in your script and you type:

```sh
./script.sh -c -b -f
```

`-b` is considered as the argument of option `-c`, not as an option itself.

##### Details

Considering this part of your question: "*it looks like it fails to work when I do not give the flags in the -b -f ... -c ... order*", let's assume you want the `b` option to have no argument, and the `f` and `c` options to have one.

If your option has no argument don't put a colon after it in the `optstring` parameter; else put the colon **after** the option character. With your simple example you could try:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
x=0
fopt=""
copt=""

while getopts bf:c: opt; do
  case "$opt" in
    b) x=1;;
    f) echo "f option found"; fopt="$OPTARG";;
    c) echo "c option found"; copt="$OPTARG";;
    ?) echo "";;
  esac
done

echo "x is ${x}"
echo "fopt is ${fopt}"
echo "copt is ${copt}"
```

And then:

```sh
$ ./script.sh -b -c foo -f bar
c option found
f option found
x is 1
fopt is bar
copt is foo
$ ./script.sh -c foo -f bar
c option found
f option found
x is 0
fopt is bar
copt is foo
$ ./script.sh -c foo -b
c option found
x is 1
fopt is 
copt is foo
```

But be careful: with the last example, if you omit the `foo` argument of the `-c` option:

```sh
./script.sh -c -b
c option found
x is 0
fopt is 
copt is -b
```

See? `-b` became the missing argument and has not been considered as an option. Is it the cause of your problem?

> Note: If you want to also use long options don't use the bash `getopts` builtin, use the `getopt` utility.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explenation! Works great :)